# How to create an online Python IDE that can take user input

Tags: python, flask, ide

I am developing a web Python IDE in Flask that has drag and drop code elements for pedagogical purposes (that according to theory ought to make it easier for children to learn to code). It has an editor and output and draggable code elements. So far I can drag the code elements into the editor and run the code in the editor and I have output. The difficulty arises when I try to incorporate user input into the online editor. So for instance if I enter:

```
name=input("What is your name? ")
```

into my editor then the application hangs.  I know precisely why it does this, but I do not have a solution.  I use subprocess, but I don't think it helps me with solving this problem. This is the code I have so far:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import subprocess

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        code = request.form["code"]
        result = subprocess.run(["python", "-c", code], capture_output = True, text = True)
        output=result.stdout+result.stderr
        return render_template("index.html", code=code, output=output)

    return render_template("index.html", code="")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and the HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mango Python IDE</title>
<style>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}

button {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

pre {
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Mango Python IDE</h1>
    <p class="drag-me" draggable="true">string=input()</p>
    <p class="drag-me" draggable="true">print("")</p>
    <p class="drag-me" draggable="true">num=int(input())</p>
    <form action="/" method="POST" id="codeForm">
    <textarea id="code" name="code">{{ code }}</textarea>
    <button type="submit" form="codeForm">Run</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="code" id="codeInput">
    </form>

    <pre>{{ output }}</pre>
    
<script>
document.querySelectorAll('.drag-me').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.textContent);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', e.target.outerHTML);
  });
});
</script>
    
</body>
</html>
```